# angular 7 ngrx trigger subscription of all the fields when one field is updated

Tags: angular, ngrx

Hi I am using Ngrx as the state management for my frontend project. Recently I found all the subscriptions are triggered when one field in the state is updated.

Suppose I have a state with field A and B. Correspondingly, I have AComponent and BComponent subscribing the value of A and B. Now if I keep dispatching an action to update A. the subscription of B will also be triggered all the time even though the value of B is not updated.

At the moment, what I am doing is in the subscription function of B, I check whether or not the value is changed, such as

```
if (this.B !== B) {
    //do something
}
```

Is there any way that if I dispatch an action to update A, the subscription of B is not triggered? Or this is the a fundamental mechanism of NGRX?

Thank you

**Update**

Here is the selector I am using

```
this._store
  .select("appState")
  .pipe<T>(pluck("B"))
  .subscribe(callback);
```

**Update 2**

According to @Anarno's answer, I added the selector as follow

```
const BFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<string>('b');
export const BSelector = createSelector(
    BFeatureSelector,
    state => state
);
```

At the meanwhile, I print a message in reducer to make sure B is updated as

```
case app.ActionType.B: {
    console.info("b is update in reducter");
    return Object.assign({}, state, { b: action.payload });
}
```

And then I use this BSelector in BComponent in the following three methods

```
this._store.select(BSelector).subscribe(b=> {
  console.info("b is updated 1");
  console.info(b);
});

this._store
  .pipe(
    map(state => BSelector(state))
  )
  .subscribe(b=> {
    console.info("b is updated 2");
    console.info(b);
  });

this._store
  .pipe(select(notificationSelector))
  .subscribe(b=> {
    console.info("b is updated 3");
    console.info(b);
  });
```

What I observe is both `b is updated 1` and `b is updated 3` only printed once when the component is initialised while `b is updated 2` is printed all the time when other fields in state is updated. However, none of `console.info(b);` in each method works. All three methods do not print the content of b.

Comment: This is not the fundamental mechanism. I think you have some problem with your selectors. Please share more code.

Comment: Thank you Anarno, I updated my questions with the example of the selector I am using

Comment: I think you have problem with your selctors, pls take a look at https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors here.

Comment: Because you don't use selectors, your subscription always takes the full state, and every time makes an emit. This is why your all subscriptions makes emits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a selector file, and make selectors like this:

```js
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { BState } from '../../../reducers/index';

const selectBState = createFeatureSelector<BState>('BState');

export const selectBvalue = createSelector(
  selectBState,
  state => state.value
);
```

Comment: Thank you Anarno, I updated my question with your suggestion. Could you please have a look.

Comment: A feature selector is select a piece of state, and a common selector select an attribute in the feature state. You try select B feature but you only need B attribute. If you have only one main state you need select this state with a feature selector, then select the B attribute with a common selector. Like this: ` const selectMainState = createFeatureSelector('mainState') ; export const selectBattribute = createSelector( selectMainState, state => state.Battribute); `